# How is PCM audio data processed on a PC?

Tags: audio, pcm

I know that in a DSP for example, the samples are being processed one by one. On a PC afaik, the data is processed in blocks of samples. So do you introduce block by block and discard the old one or is it processed in a FIFO queue or circular buffer? Does it depend in the hardware?

Comment: what do you mean processed ?  rendered into sound ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen audio data edited on either a per-frame basis or on a batch basis. I'm guessing when you say "sample" you are referring to the individual PCM audio values that make up the signal. The method you choose is going to depend on the tradeoffs, for example, if organizing operations on a per frame basis takes a higher priority than maximizing throughput.

I've seen two ways in which audio is routed to the system for playback, either as a series of arrays copied into predefined locations (e.g., as done with [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org/documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf)), or via writing arrays to a line that employs a blocking queue (e.g., Java's [SourceDataLine.write()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int)) method).